# React - generalize dynamic array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if I'm following an advisable/correct pattern but basically, my application leverages on same arrays used in various components.

I am thinking about generalizing these lists as constants for simplicity/maintainability.

Here follows an example: I have two different arrays with fixed labels but dynamic contents. The first array retrieves the content info using the "props" I am passing to the contents while the second one uses new data fetched with useEffects.

Note that I render these arrays in many different ways so it may be better to not fix the rendering.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

export default function App({ props }: Props) {

  const [dataIntegration, setDataIntegration] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataIntegration = async () => {
      const { data, error } = await client
        .from("someTable").select("*").eq("id", props.id);

      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
      }
      if (data) {
        setDataIntegration(data[0]);
      }
    };
    fetchDataIntegration();
  }, []);

  const items1 = [
    { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 1", variableContent: props?.content1 },
    { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 2", variableContent: props?.content2 },
  ];

  const items2 = [
    { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 1", variableContent: dataIntegration?.content1 },
    { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 2", variableContent: dataIntegration?.content2 },
  ]; 

  return (
     <div>
       <div>
         {items1.map((item1) => (
           <div key={item2.fixedLabel}>
             <div>
               {item1.variableContent}
             </div>
           </div>
          ))}
      </div>
      <div>
         {items2.map((item2) => (
           <div key={item2.fixedLabel}>
             <div>
               {item2.variableContent}
             </div>
           </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of things that could break in the piece of code that you shared, but, to answer your question, I would create a utility function, that take your variableContentes as parameters and return your items arrays.Your could storage that utility function into a utils.ts file that exporters it

Comment: How would you improve this code? for simplicity in the example I have deliberately omitted the error handling in the _fetchDataIntegration()_ function and the rendering in the case of no retrieved data

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, when working on big codebases it's generally a good idea to put these arrays or any constant data in a constant file for ease of maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in wanting to generalize these. Whenever you have code that is very repetitive - as the items1, items2, etc suggests - you should try to simplify.

So instead of doing:

```
    const items1 = [
    { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 1", variableContent: props?.content1 },
    { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 2", variableContent: props?.content2 },
  ];

  const items2 = [
    { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 1", variableContent: dataIntegration?.content1 },
    { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 2", variableContent: dataIntegration?.content2 },
  ];
```

It would be better maintainable and reusable like this:

```
const item = (label, variabeleContent) => {
  return {
    label: label,
    content: variabeleContent,
    };
}
```

From there, you can fill up array with items or call them manually.

Comment: I'm very n00b but I can't figure out how to implement your solution.
I ended up with this:
costants.js file:
`
export const items1 = [
  { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 1", variableContent: (props) => props?.content1 },
  { f/* etc */ },
];

export const items2 = [
  { fixedLabel: "Fixed Label 1", variableContent: (props) => props?.content1 },
  { f/* etc */ },
];`

And then use them in my components in the map with `<div>{item.variableContent(props)}</div>`